# Change the color of the row localstorage?

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

here is the html

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        1
    </td>
     <td>
        2
    </td>
     <td>
        3
    </td>
     <td>
         <input type ="button" value = "change" class = "change" />
    </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>
        4
    </td>
     <td>
        5
    </td>
     <td>
        6
    </td>
     <td>
         <input type ="button" value = "change" class = "change" />
    </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>
        7
    </td>
     <td>
        8
    </td>
     <td>
        9
    </td>
     <td>
         <input type ="button" value = "change" class = "change" />
    </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>
        7
    </td>
     <td>
        8
    </td>
     <td>
        13
    </td>
     <td>
         <input type ="button" value = "change" class = "change" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

here is my `jquery`

```
 $(".change").click(function(e){
 debugger;
    localStorage.setItem("visited" + $(this).closest("tr").index(), true);
    $(this).css("color", "red"); // visited
});

 for(var i = 0, len = $(".change").length; i < len; i++) {

if(localStorage.getItem("visited" + i)) {
    $(".change").eq(i).css("color", "white").prop('disabled', true).val('generated'); // visited
} else {
    $(".change").eq(i).css("color", "black"); // not visited
}
}
});
```

**problem**

```
-only the odd numbers of row button is affected.
-how shiuld i change the background color of the row on button click.
```

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LUBKj/1/

Comment: i want to change the background color not the button

Comment: then instead of `color` use `background-color`

Comment: bacckground color of which element

Comment: background color of the row of which the button is clicked and after visit the button should be disable and the row color also should be different

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LUBKj/2/ ?

Comment: background color of 123 shod be chang on click

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `id` to your `tr` element and on click of button call the javascript function which will change the background color of the row. Demo code shown below:

**HTML Code**

```
<tr id="rowid1">
    <td>
        1
    </td>
    <td>
        2
    </td>
    <td>
        3
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="change" class="change" onclick="javascript:changecolor('rowid1')" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function changecolor(rowid)
{
    alert(rowid);
    document.getElementById(rowid).style.backgroundColor="lightblue";
}
```